# Cordova 6.0 external links

Tags: cordova, hyperlink, inappbrowser

I'm building a Cordova APP for iOS and Android that has links to external websites but all links open in the System Browser and I want to open inside the APP.

My links are simple `<a href="someURLlink">` links. I already installed the inappbrowser plugin but it seems not to work.

Any help or working examples can help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var iab = cordova.InAppBrowser;

iab.open('http://whitelisted-url.com');                  // loads in the Cordova WebView
iab.open('http://whitelisted-url.com', '_self');         // loads in the Cordova WebView
iab.open('http://whitelisted-url.com', '_system');       // loads in the system browser
iab.open('http://whitelisted-url.com', '_blank');        // loads in the InAppBrowser
iab.open('http://whitelisted-url.com', 'random_string'); // loads in the InAppBrowser
```